# CKQuerySubscription: Failing to Make Subscription

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have an iOS app that I'm working on with **CloudKit**.  And I'm trying to make a subscription.

```
import CloudKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        registerSubscription()
    }

    func registerSubscription() {
        let cloudContainer = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.xxx.XXXXX")
        let privateDB = cloudContainer.privateCloudDatabase
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE") // TRUEPREDICATE: all records of the specified type match the predicate
        let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "PrivateRecords", predicate: predicate, options: .firesOnRecordCreation)
        privateDB.save(subscription, completionHandler: ({returnRecord, error in
            if let err = error {
                print("Subscription has failed: \(err.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Subscription set up successfully")
                print("Subscription ID: \(subscription.subscriptionID)")
            }
        }))
    }
}
```

And it will consistently go to the error.  The error says the following.

> Subscription with a nil notificationInfo: CKQuerySubscription: 0x7fd7bfca7ec0; ; Query Subscription: recordType=PrivateRecords, predicate=TRUEPREDICATE, subscriptionOptions=1, subscriptionID=728863F8-3852-4A12-B5C6-F65EC945207A, zoneID=(null)

I can delete the subscription based on the subscription ID.  But it'll give me a different ID every time I run this app.  I have actually done the same thing with a **macOS** application.  And it has a subscription.  Additionally, I deleted a subscription type about a week ago to see what happens.  I don't really know what the subscription ID is for.

So what am I doing wrong in making a subscription?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: As the message implies, you need to set the `notificationInfo` property of `subscription` before you save it.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you.  That is it.  If you put it there as a solution, I'll accept it.

Comment: By the way, you can use `NSPredicate(value: true)` instead of `NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")`. It looks a little nicer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CKQuerySubscription` extends `CKSubscription`. One of the properties you need to set before saving the subscription is `notificationInfo`. The message is pointing out that this property is `nil` and should be set to something useful.

Answer (score 2):

CKQuerySubscriptions have a property notificationInfo, what you'll need to do is something like the following:

```
let notification = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
notification.alertBody = "You have a new message"
notification.shouldSendContentAvailable = true

newSubscription.notificationInfo = notification
```